# How to count regex match for ' but not \' in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I know basics of how to process regex in javascript. i can count ' and \' in the string. but how to match ' and not \' in a string. As of now i have a workaround by subtracting the results of both the matches. is it possible to find the count includes ' and excludes \' in a single regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you don't have [negative lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), so you can't easily check if there is an odd number of backslashes before a `'` unless you make those characters part of the match.

Therefore, you need to do something a bit more complicated - match all the strings that end in a single, unescaped quote, effectively splitting the entire input into chunks, one for each quote. Then count those chunks:

```
/[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'/g
```

will match all those parts of the string.

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qZ9dX9/1).

**Explanation:**

```
[^\\']*   # Match any number of characters except backslashes and quotes.
(?:       # Start of non-capturing group: Match...
 \\.      # an escaped character (any escape sequence like \' or etc.),
 [^\\']*  # followed by any number of characters except backslashes and quotes.
)*        # Do this as often as needed (even 0 times)
'         # until you can match a single (unescaped) quote
```